# ArcGIS API for SIlverlight 3.1 SIlverlight 5: Esri identify task

Tags: silverlight-5.0, arcgis, identify, dataitem

RE: ArcGIS API for SIlverlight 3.1 SIlverlight 5: Need help with identify task

```
I have the following using statements:
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Client;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Geometry;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Printing;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Tasks;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Toolkit;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Toolkit.Primitives;
```

but I get an error in this line:

```
private List<DataItem> dataItems = null;
```

The type or namespace name 'DataItem' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The DataItem class is just used to define your object to bind your data to the view. If you look at the code for the [identify sample](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/silverlight-api/samples/start.htm#Identify) in the interactive SDK the DataItem is defined at the bottom of the file

```
public class DataItem
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public IDictionary<string, object> Data { get; set; }
    }
```